# cellClicked and cellPressed not working for QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Whats is wrong with following call. IDBTable is QTableWidget

```
connect(m_GUI->m_UI->IDBTable,SIGNAL(cellPressed(2, 0)), this, SLOT(slotGoToWelcomeScreen()));
```

Comment: Replace `SIGNAL(cellPressed(2, 0))` with `SIGNAL(cellPressed(int, int))`. Then you can call `cellPressed(2,0)` to trigger `slotGoToWelcomeScreen`.

Answer (score 1):

Your signal definition is wrong. There is no such signal `cellPressed(2, 0)` but only `cellPressed(int, int)`. Please read the [documentation about signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and prefer the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) to catch such errors during compile time.